# Problem to display .tiff pictures when they are too large with vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, binary, base64, tiff

I can display .tiff pictures on my navigator, with this function :

```
GDAL.gdal_translate(tifDataset, options).then((output) => {
  GDAL.getFileBytes(output).then((bytes) => {
    base64Data = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes));

    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Data;
    elm.appendChild(img);
    const body = document.querySelector("body");
  });
});
```

But, if the picture is too voluminous, i have an error in my console :

**Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

I don't know how to resolve it, please help me !

Comment: Is this where you're getting `GDAL`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal

Comment: What is elm? Why are you getting the body using querySelector whe document.body is a thing. Why do you get body then don't use it for anything

Comment: The issue is `base64Data = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes));` ... what type of data is bytes?

Comment: @Samathingamajig no, i'm getting GDAL by a link : https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gdal3.js@2.2.0/dist/package/gdal3.js in a script tag

Comment: The type of data of bytes is Uint8Array @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of `bytes` is causing the issue with `String.fromCharCode.apply` ... you can't have hundreds of thousands of arguments for a function

try this instead

```
base64Data = btoa(bytes.toString().split(',').map(c => String.fromCharCode(c)).join(''))
```

or perhaps better

```
base64Data = btoa([...bytes].map(c => String.fromCharCode(c)).join(''))
```